# Why is the Docker service stopping?

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu as a subsystem on Windows 10.

I have just followed the steps to install Docker on Linux:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

And are now at the step to test the hello-world app:

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
```

Where I get this error:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

I have narrowed it down to that it actually is the service that is not running - despite lots of other solutions online that more or less fixes this type of error.

When I check the status:

```
$ sudo service docker status
* Docker is not running
```

It says it's not running so I start it successfully:

```
$ sudo service docker start
* Starting Docker: docker                                                                                       [ OK ]
```

If I check the status immediately it says it's running. But when I check it again a few second later, it's not runnning:

```
$ sudo service docker status
* Docker is running

$ sudo service docker status
* Docker is not running
```

Why is the Docker service stopping and how can I keep it running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you got is as expected.

Microsoft does not support running the Docker daemon (also known as the service) within the WSL instance. You can refer to [this discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/1352813/does-the-wsl-from-windows-10-spring-update-2018-allows-me-to-run-docker-on-it).

What you can do is just use `docker client` in WSL to connect to a remote docker engine which means `docker daemon` still on other PC.

But, if you use [WSL2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/) which announced in `May 6th, 2019`, then, from microsoft's announcement, it could be(There is also a demo in this announcement which you can have a look):

> Today we’re unveiling the newest architecture for the Windows Subsystem for Linux: WSL 2! Changes in this new architecture will allow for: dramatic file system performance increases, and full system call compatibility, meaning you can run more Linux apps in WSL 2 such as Docker.

Comment: You know what version of Windows is WSL2 enabled? A comment mentioned 1903 but I don't think that was final.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried it, but from this [discussion](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/132527-wsl-1-wsl-2-upgrade.html), one guy said: `talked to Microsoft Support last night and she said it will update to WSL2 in the May 21st Windows update automatically.` Seems need to update patch... Original 1903 definitely not support as it just release 2 month ago.

Answer (score 0):

You need either Docker on Windows:
https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4